# How to create a stored procedure with columns from three different tables in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I'm a fresher and I would like to get some suggestions on how to create a stored procedure in which I have to select columns from three different tables. 2 columns `customername` and `customercode` from first table, `loan type` from second table and `account number`, `status` from 3rd table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    C.customername 
    ,C.customercode
    ,L.[loan type] 
    ,S.[account number]
    ,S.status
FROM
    [first table] AS C
    INNER JOIN [second table] AS L
    ON C.customercode = L.customercode
    INNER JOIN  [3rd table] AS S
    ON S.customercode = C.customercode
```

This is only as a guidance; it is better to post some sample data and definitions.